# merge some rows in condition

Tags: python, csv

I want to merge rows within a condition. If the length of the row less than  20, merge this row with the one before it.
I'm try with this code but the output is not correct
Thank for your help.
[image: The photo describe what I want]

```
import csv 

datam = []
with open("All.csv", 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    doc = line
    datam.append(doc)
with open('Test.csv', mode = 'w',newline ='',encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=' ')
    for i, data in enumerate(datam):
        if len(datam)< 20:
            writer.writerow([datam[i-1] + ',' + datam[i]])
            datam.remove(data[i])
        if len(data)>= 20:
            writer.writerow([datam[i]])
```

Comment: Why the output is not correct? Please add an example of what do you expect and what do you get with your code instead

Comment: @Valentino I have added a picture that explains what is required

Comment: @snakecharmerb What do I want from the code, if the length of the row less than 20 character, merge this row with previous row then delete it. the code merge this row that less than 20 char, but keep two rows. I need just one row from these two rows. please take a look on output and desired output in the picture. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

Your code seems to be checking the length of `datum` -- which is the number of lines, rather than the length of a particular line.

We can rearrange the logic a little by always checking the length of the *next* line in each iteration. If its shorter than 20, we combine it with the current line and write to the output CSV; then remove that line. Otherwise, we just write the current line to the CSV.

There's an edge case where we are at the last line of the input CSV, in which case we have no subsequent line to check, so we just write the line to the output CSV directly.

Finally, the code at the start can be greatly simplified. Its a bit confusing since you're reading the source file into `lines`, then copying it line by line into `datam`. You can do this is one go.

Also, there's a small bug in that the original file will contain newlines, which you will want to strip.

The following should work for you:

```
import csv 

with open('All.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  datam = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]

with open('Test.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    rows = []
    for i, data in enumerate(datam):
        if i + 1 == len(datam):
            writer.writerow([data])
        elif len(datam[i + 1]) < 20:
            writer.writerow([data + ',' + datam[i + 1]])
            datam.remove(datam[i + 1])
        elif len(datam[i + 1]) >= 20:
            writer.writerow([data])
```

Comment: This code gives me the same old result. I have added a picture in the question explaining what is required. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @user14462764 please see the updated response which should produce the expected output, the original solved a slightly different problem

Comment: The code is now correct. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I have a question please. If I want to apply the same process but in new case that I have two column and I wanna apply the condition in code in the second column and do the same process if any row have less than 20 char remove the row for two column

Comment: This is a different requirement, so should be asked as a new question.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your response

Comment: I added the question. could you please see the question.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65589445/merge-some-rows-in-two-conditions).

Comment: Will try and check tomorrow if I get a chance and no one has responded by then